# How to only render fragments with Z from 0 to 1 in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, clipping, frustum-culling

I have been using OpenGL for a year now, but I just recently found out that OpenGL only clips vertices when the absolute value of the x,y or z coordinate is less than the absolute value of w coordinate. Previously I had assumed that the z coordinate would have to be 0 < z < w to be rendered. Is there any way to clip vertices with z less than 0, without a performance hit?

I am using OpenGL 4.4

Answer (score 3):

I believe that OpenGL's standard clipping volume is *[-1, 1] x [-1, 1] x [-1, 1]*. You want to clip at *[-1, 1] x [-1, 1] x [0, 1]*. You can achieve this by transforming the z-coordinate after all transformations have been applied to the vertex position (model, view and projection transforms). In other words, you want to operate on the screen coordinates of the vertex.

---

## On Homogeneous Coordinates

I'll quickly go over the ***w* coordinate** you are mentioning, so you understand what is happening. The w-coordinate is used to represent a **3D point** in a **4D homogeneous representation**. This representation is used to make matrix math more simple. Specifically, it lets you use a 4x4 matrix to perform translations, something which you can not do with a 3x3 matrix and 3D point representations.

As you are using a 4D representation for a 3D point, many combinations of 4 coordinates will describe the same 3D point. The actual position of your point can be obtained by dividing all components of the 4D representation by *w*. So for example, point [x,y,z,w] is located at the following 3D coordinates: [x/w, y/w, z/w].

This explains why you observed clipping at *z > w*. As in fact, the z-coordinate becomes *z/w*. Knowing that clipping occurs at z-coordinate > 1, you'll find that this is at:

```
    z-coordinate > 1
<=> z/w > 1
<=> z > w
```

---

## Solution: Clipping Between Z-Values 0 and 1

If you want to **clip in range [0, 1]** instead of the default [-1, 1], you simply need to **remap the z-coordinate** to this range. You'll want to do this after all vertex transformations have been applied in your **vertex shader**, so that you are working with **screen coordinates**. These are the coordinates where clipping is applied.

To remap, simply do:

```
z_new = (z_old * 2) - 1;
```

This will make sure, vertices which originally had z-coordinate 0, get mapped to -1. Coordinates with an original z-coordinate of 1 stay at 1. Everything in between is a linear interpolation of the two.

As you are just doing a small additional calculation per vertex in your vertex shader, you won't notice a hit in performance.

Comment: Your solution is perfectly adequate, however I also need the increased precision floats have near the 0 value so a simple remapping is not enough. I have found [this](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glClipControl.xhtml), but I am working on Linux and currently restrained to OpenGL 4.4.

Comment: I see, that's more difficult to solve indeed. You could try a logarithmic remapping to get more precision near 0. However, doing this will give you most precision at your far plane. Typically, you want most precision in the focus-point/ center (depth-wise) of your view, rather than at your near or far plane. Are you developing a very specific use case that requires precision for distant geometry?

Comment: The short answer is yes. The long answer is a bit more complicated, but essentially what I need is for every vertex with z<0 to be discarded. I will try to use the [ARB_clip_control](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/clip_control.txt) extension, but I have no idea how to use OpenGL extensions as of this moment.